# PageControl dosn't animate when swiping to next picture

Tags: swift, uipagecontrol, pagecontrol

I have an array of pictures that are past to an imageView on a new ViewController. I'm able to have my pageControl show the dots, but they do not animate when I swipe to the next picture. Any ideas on what I am missing as I cannot figure it out? Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds


class imageViewController: UIViewController,GADBannerViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!


    var passedImage : UIImage! = nil
    var passedArray : [UIImage]!
    var index = 0


    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myImageView.image = passedArray.first

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0

        configurePageControl()


        //---------ADS----------------
        // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
        addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return myImageView
    }

    func configurePageControl() {
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = passedArray.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)

    }



    @IBAction func pictureswipe(_ sender: Any) {
        let pictureString = self.passedArray[index]
        self.myImageView.image = pictureString

        index = (index < passedArray.count-1) ? index+1 : 0
    }

    @IBAction func pictureswipeback(_ sender: Any) {
        let pictureString = self.passedArray[index]
        self.myImageView.image = pictureString

        index = (index > passedArray.count+1) ? index-1 : 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `pageControl`'s `currentPage` with your new index as well, try to update your `IBAction` methods as following.

```
    @IBAction func pictureswipe(_ sender: Any) {
    let pictureString = self.passedArray[index]
    self.myImageView.image = pictureString
    self.pageControl.currentPage = index
    index = (index < passedArray.count-1) ? index+1 : 0

}

@IBAction func pictureswipeback(_ sender: Any) {
    let pictureString = self.passedArray[index]
    self.myImageView.image = pictureString
    self.pageControl.currentPage = index
    index = (index > passedArray.count+1) ? index-1 : 0
}
```